# How to limit the time in showTimePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, timepicker

I need to set Time limit at TimePicker. like i need to set time picker in between 12pm to 6pm and another time i don't want to select from user.

In older version of flutter they provide allowedHours and allowedMinutes but in new version they hide that properties.

Older version code:-

```
showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    allowedHours: [8,9,10,11,12, 15,16,17],
    allowedMinutes: [0,10,20,30,40,50],
    displayDisabledValues: true
```

);

I want to set limit at TimePicker based on requirement. Is there any another way to set it. like any Property or any third party package?

Answer (score 1):

For example I am using 12 pm to 2 PM. Below snippet meet with your purpose.
Use a packager name `time_range_picker: ^2.2.0`. Time range start:

```
    TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 00),
                      end: TimeOfDay(hour: 02, minute: 00)
```

Implementation :

```
   return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                TimeRange result = await showTimeRangePicker(
                  context: context,
                  start: TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 00),
                  end: TimeOfDay(hour: 02, minute: 00)
                );
                print("result " + result.toString());
              },
              child: Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("Show Time Picker")),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

package link : [time_range_picker: ^2.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/time_range_picker)